# Spider ID: What is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This crawled on my husband. It didn’t bite him, he was able to swat it away so that’s why it looks a little messed up. I honestly just want to know if this is poisonous. We live in AZ, Goodyear area and there’s usually only regular house spiders running around. There were no marking on the abdomen or thorax, the legs seem 2 toned but I couldn’t get a good look. It wasn’t more than an inch big but it has a thicker build.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77hZf.jpg)[image]

Answer (score 3):

This looks to me like a female of the common and harmless Southern House Spider, Kukulcania hibernalis (see below).

https://bugguide.net/node/view/508965

[image]

Comment: Yes, nice match.